# Как переместить аргумент Python

Tags: python

Как сделать так чтобы когда я писал my_dog2.jump() , сначало писалось print("собака прыгнула") и только потом значение аргумента , то есть кличка собаки

```
class Dog():

    """Простая модель собаки"""

    def __init__(self , name , age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        

    def sit(self):
        """Собака будет садиться по командe"""
        print(self.name.title() + " с кличкой , села")
     
    def jump(self):
        """Собака будет прыгать по команде"""
        print(self.name.title() + " собака прыгнула")   

my_dog = Dog("Aktos" , 3)

my_dog2 = Dog("Tuigin" , 5)

print(my_dog.name)

print(my_dog.age)

print(my_dog2.name)

print(my_dog2.age)

my_dog.sit()

my_dog2.jump()
```

Comment: `print(f"Собака прыгнула. \n{self.name.title()}")`

Answer (score 1):

Я рекомендую вам обратить внимание на [форматирование строк в питоне](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) и в часности на [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)
Вам достаточно сделать так:

```
class Dog():

    """Простая модель собаки"""

    def __init__(self , name , age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        

    def sit(self):
        """Собака будет садиться по командe"""
        print(self.name.title() + " с кличкой , села")
     
    def jump(self):
        """Собака будет прыгать по команде"""
        print(f"собака прыгнула {self.name.title()}")  # строка типа f"abc{var} называется f-string  

my_dog = Dog("Aktos" , 3)

my_dog2 = Dog("Tuigin" , 5)

print(my_dog.name)

print(my_dog.age)

print(my_dog2.name)

print(my_dog2.age)

my_dog.sit()

my_dog2.jump()
```